# Magento 2 : Why my module is on the vendor and app folder?

Tags: magento2, module, composer, multi-vendor, vendor

I use these commands to install my dependencies today:

```
composer config repositories.myvendor_cli vcs git@github.com:myvendor/my-cli.git
composer require myvendor/cli:dev-master
```

To work well I ever need to add the parameter `"no-api": true`,

The result in my composer it's like that:

```
...
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "myvendor/cli": "dev-master"
},
...
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "myvendor_cli": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/myvendor/extension-cli.git",
        "no-api": true
    }
},
...
```

When I run the composer update I see the module installed in two folders:

```
app/code/MyVendor/CLI/
vendor/MyVendor/CLI/
```

The Magento doesn't permit the same installation on both folders, how can I set to install just to vendor folder?